# how to insert a movie clip into my game?

Tags: android

im making an android game and i want to insert a movie clip (.flv) of exlosion into the game, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Android only supports the video formats specified here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Convert the video to h.264 or mpeg-4 with a supported container, then play it with the builtin android mediaplayer and/or videoview classes.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you can use animated gif that is supported in froyo for the browser, but you can use several .png files to simulate the explotion instead a movie clip, you can see it in the [JEtBoy sample game](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/samples/JetBoy/index.html)